# Given one of De Morgan's laws, prove the other from it using equivalences.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I have one of De Morgan's laws (in propositional logic). I would like to prove the other law from the first using a sequence of equivalences (Resolution).

One is not allowed to use truth tables or the particular De Morgans law which we are trying to prove (obviously).

How can this be done?

> $\lnot (A\land B)\equiv \lnot A \lor \lnot B$
>
> $\lnot (A\lor B)\equiv \lnot A \land \lnot B$

---

[a set of resolution equivalences laws can be found on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*

Let assume $\lnot (A \land B) \equiv \lnot A \lor \lnot B$.

Then from $\lnot (A \lor B)$ using Double Negation, we get $\lnot (\lnot \lnot A \lor \lnot \lnot B) \equiv \lnot \lnot (\lnot A \land \lnot B)$.

Answer (score 0):

For future enquirers here is an unformatted solution (using @Mauro's hint) and some relabelling.

[image]